# Build error on MPLAB X for PIC32CM Microchip

Tags: pic, mplabx

I am working on a project on a Microchip PIC32CM LS00, trying to run a code found on GitHub (https://github.com/Microchip-MPLAB-Harmony/csp_apps_pic32cm_le_ls, specifically the "TrustZone basic demonstration - PIC32CMLS00" sample project).
When importing the project on MPLAB X IDE v6.05 and attempting to build it, I obtain the following error message:

```
make[2]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/[...]/apps/csp_apps_pic32cm_le_ls-master/apps/trustZone/trustZone_basic_ls00/NonSecure/firmware/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_NonSecure.X'
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1363761897/plib_nvic.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1363761897/plib_nvic.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/peripheral/nvic/plib_nvic.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1158042722/plib_sercom3_usart.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1158042722/plib_sercom3_usart.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/peripheral/sercom/usart/plib_sercom3_usart.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1918410531/xc32_monitor.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1918410531/xc32_monitor.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/stdio/xc32_monitor.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1363815048/plib_port.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1363815048/plib_port.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/peripheral/port/plib_port.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/initialization.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/initialization.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/initialization.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/interrupts.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/interrupts.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/interrupts.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../../../Secure/firmware/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_Secure.X/dist/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_Secure.X.production.hex', needed by 'dist/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_NonSecure.X.production.hex'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/exceptions.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/exceptions.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/exceptions.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/startup_xc32.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/startup_xc32.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/startup_xc32.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/1360937237/main.o ../src/main.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"C:\Program Files\Microchip\xc32\v4.21\bin\xc32-gcc.exe"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=32CM5164LS60064  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -I"../src" -I"../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/" -I"../src/packs/CMSIS/CMSIS/Core/Include" -I"../src/packs/PIC32CM5164LS00100_DFP" -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/libc_syscalls.o.d" -o build/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/production/_ext/340140899/libc_syscalls.o ../src/config/pic32cm_ls00_cpro/libc_syscalls.c    -DXPRJ_pic32cm_ls00_cpro=pic32cm_ls00_cpro      -Wformat=2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wfloat-equal -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wbad-function-cast -Wwrite-strings -Waggregate-return -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-deprecated-declarations -Wpacked -Wredundant-decls -Wnested-externs -Winline -Wunreachable-code -Wmissing-noreturn -mdfp="C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/Microchip/PIC32CM-LS_DFP/1.1.162/PIC32CM-LS60" -I "C:/Program Files/Microchip/MPLABX/v6.05/packs/arm/CMSIS/5.4.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/[...]/apps/csp_apps_pic32cm_le_ls-master/apps/trustZone/trustZone_basic_ls00/NonSecure/firmware/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_NonSecure.X'
nbproject/Makefile-pic32cm_ls00_cpro.mk:88: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/[...]/apps/csp_apps_pic32cm_le_ls-master/apps/trustZone/trustZone_basic_ls00/NonSecure/firmware/pic32cm_ls00_cpro_NonSecure.X'
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 3s)
```

I have seen this error message pop up in some other forums online, but none of the provided solutions I have tried seem to work. Help is appreciated!

EDIT: solutions I have already tried include cleaning the project before building it, ensuring the compiler paths were correct, attempting to automatically regenerate the Makefile, deleting build and dist directories, deleting [...].production.hex and pasting its content into a new file (mostly inspired from https://microchipdeveloper.com/mplabx:no-rule-to-make-target and [Makefile error with my MPLAB X](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/525144/makefile-error-with-my-mplab-x)).

Comment: Could you enumerate what provided solutions you have tried?

Comment: Apparently the file "pic32cm_ls00_cpro_Secure.X.production.hex" is missing, You should look through the Makefile about this file. Please add your findings by [edit] your question.